# Finding formula for a cubic polynomial

Tags: calculus

So I need to find a formula for a cubic polynomial with the given conditions:

- Local max at $x=1$
- Local min at $x=3$
- $Y$ intercept of $5$
- $x^3$ term whose coefficient is $1$

So all I really have is $x^3+x^2+x+5$.

I know that $F'(1) = 0$ and $F''(1) < 0$. Also $F'(3) = 0$ and $F''(3) > 0$. But as far as setting up the problem, I'm lost.

Comment: You want a *formula* or a *function*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+5$; you have $f(x)=x^3+bx^2+cx+5$ where the coefficients $b$ and $c$ are yet unknown.

Since you also have $f'(1)=0$ and $f'(3)=0$, this gives you two (linear) equations in the two unknowns $b$ and $c$ which you can solve.

This doesn't use the information that $1$ and $3$ are maximum and minimum rather than the other way around, but for a third-degree polynomial whose leading coefficient is positive, the local maximum (if any) will always come before the local minimum (if any), so that is automatically satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the first derivative of a cubic polynomial will be a quadratic, suppose $g(x)$.

According to the question, the function has local maxima and local minima at $1$ and $3$ respectively. Hence we have $f'(x)=g(x)=0$ at $x=1,3$. Therefore $g(x)$ can be written as
$$\begin{align}
g(x)&=A(x-1)(x-3)\\
g(x)&=A(x^2-4x+3)\\
f(x)&=A\int (x^2-4x+3~dx)\\
\end{align}$$

Finally apply the condition $f(0)=5$ to get the constant of integration and use the fact that the coefficient of $x^3$ has to be 1 to get A.

Comment: $kg(x)$ also satisfies the zero derivative conditions for constant $k$.

Comment: If you're only starting with local maxima and minima, you should get $g(x) = A(x - 1)(x - 3)$ so that you are left with two degrees of freedom; $A$ and the constant of integration $C$. These are then found by $f(0) = 5$ and $A = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 coefficients to your equation:

${x^3} + a{x^2} + bx + 5$

Then I think you should be able to solve for a & b using only the 1st derivatives.